# ASP.NET 5 MySql Support

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am developing a Green Field Application in ASP.NET 5 using Visual Studio 2015.

I want to know that if I am running it in Linux environment the database used is MySql Workbench

How we do this?

It is my core problem in doing this business.

Comment: Please explain a bit more clearly what the question is

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation-unix.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation.html

This page clearly mention that you can use Mysql.Data.dll on any framework. If mysql.data.dll library is not working for you. You can compile it yourself on your linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

MySql support Linux environment also. So You will not face any major problem.

But yes, You will have to write Table & column names in small letter in your queries otherwise it will give error.